# How to produce a 3-column list?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have to produce a 3-column list of items similar to what can be seen for the different groups (mostly banks and financial institutions) at this page:

http://funds.ft.com/FundDirectory.aspx (even though these are horizontally aligned divs)

I have all the items I need to add to the 3 columns in a `List<Group>` stored in my `Model.Groups` object.

I was thinking of taking an approach similar to:

```
<ul>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.Groups) { %>

        <li>
            <a href='<%=item.URL %>'>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %>
            </a>
        </li>

    <% } %>
</ul>
```

but this will only generate a single-column list. Is there any way for me to produce a 3-column list with simple HTML/CSS or do I have to take a more dynamic approach, by e.g. creating 3 horizontally aligned lists, with the number of items per list depending on the total number of items in `Model.Groups` / 3?

Or is there a smarter way for me to approach this? I'm open to all suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the simplest and most effective answer I've found:

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=27f87

To quote the site:

```
The HTML:
<ul>
  <li>Antelope</li>
  <li>Bison</li>
  <li>Camel</li>
  <li>Deer</li>
  <li>Eland</li>
  <li>Gazelle</li>
</ul>

The CSS:
ul {
  float: left;
  width: 12em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 6em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

> "If we want more columns we can widen the list and and add more list items"

Comment: This has the disadvantage that it will order the items across instead of down, which is not how most people read a columned list.

Answer (score 7):

CSS3 `column` styles can be used on a list as well:

```
<ul class="group-list">
    ...
</ul>

.group-list {
    -moz-column-gap: 20;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20;
}
```

You can add [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and this [jQuery column plugin](http://codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery) to support old versions of IE:

```
if (!Modernizr.csscolumns) {
        $('.group-list').makeacolumnlists({cols: 3, colWidth: 240, equalHeight: false, startN: 1});
}
```

PPK has a good article on [CSS3 column support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) in browsers, and [caniuse.com has a page on CSS3 Multiple column layout](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count) too.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered about an hour ago here: [How do I overflow the contents of a column into the next column using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196677/how-do-i-overflow-the-contents-of-a-column-into-the-next-column-using-css)

Comment: I think they kind of are. I think that you should be able to use the CSS property on the list.

Answer (score 0):

If it´s an unordered list, you can just float the `li`'s left and give them a width of 33%.