# How can I force an odd column-count when I have an even number of columns?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout, column-count

I've got a columns class that sets the number of CSS columns to three.  This looks like the following:

```css
.columns {
  column-count:3;
  -moz-column-count:3;
  -webkit-column-count:3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="columns">
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Grapes</li>
  <li>Pears</li>
  <li>Bananas</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like this to be displayed in the following format:

`Apples      Grapes      Pears
 Bananas`

This can be seen on this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fM8ce/1/

If I remove bananas then all three columns are used as expected and is outputted in the following way:

`Apples      Grapes      Pears`

This can be seen in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fM8ce/

How can I get four items to be distributed as expected, across three columns rather than 2?

Comment: This is not how the columns feature works. It's meant for automatically breaking long texts into multiple columns. As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/N9Ych/

Comment: That also breaks if the text can be spread across four cells:  http://jsfiddle.net/N9Ych/1/

Comment: Your example just provides to less text for your browser width. Make your window smaller in width and watch it break into the 3rd column.

Comment: I agree that css 3 columns magic is for breaking content, not lists; but in this case it looks more like a bug than like a feature. If it works with 4 columns in other way than with 3 columns it is better to avoid it and use other list positioning tricks, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197110/how-to-produce-a-3-column-list. It is all basic CSS margins, heights et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible using css columns.

It looks like you should simply use `display:inline-block` or `float:left` so achieve your layout - like this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fM8ce/4/)

```
<ul class="columns">
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Grapes</li>
    <li>Pears</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.columns {
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    width: 33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The reason why I don't think you really want to use css columns is because you yourself write that you want to  achieve:

`Apples      Grapes      Pears
Bananas`

whereas even if it were possible with css columns - the final result would be:

`Apples      Pears      Bannanas
Grapes`

because css columns works down the columns first.