# How to display dynamic content in two divs, with definite height for each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long html content(html snippet) fetch from server side, I would like to display it on a page with two divs, say, `div1` and `div2`, each div with definite height, **no scroll bar in a div is allowed**, **the html content is dynamic**, maybe long or short, if it's too large to fit in `div1`, it will automatically expand to `div2`, rather than displaying all content in `div1` with long scrolling bar.

is it possible to do it? How?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes this is possible, although determining the height at which to split the content will not be easy.

Comment: You are try to append overflow content to different div.

Comment: [is there a way to fire a event when vertical overflow is detected in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092137/is-there-a-way-to-fire-a-event-when-vertical-overflow-is-detected-in-a-div)

Comment: Is using two `div`s part of your real requirements, or could you do with just one `div` with CSS 'column' set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196677/how-do-i-overflow-the-contents-of-a-column-into-the-next-column-using-css or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542909/2-css-columns-spliing-text-into-next-column

Comment: @abhitalks good questions! thanks all for the links will look into it later.

Comment: Give your code sample..

Comment: @July: In that case you could use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gj8hf54t/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your content to be equally distributed, then you can split your content in two parts. And then you can show in two seperate divs. Something like this:

```
var content = getContent(); // getContent() is a method by which you are getting the content
var len = content.length;
var halfContent = content.substring(0, len/2);
var secondHalf = content.substring(len - len/2, len);
document.getElementById('div1').innerText = halfContent;
document.getElementById('div2').innerText = secondHalf;
```

Comment: This divides content exactly into two, without seeing if the content is overflowing. I think the question was to move the overflowing content only.